# Why is NoClassDefFoundError thrown with "run" but works fine with "dist"?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, h2, slick, jts

Before I asked the question I had read the question [Play framework java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError only in dev mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18878707/play-framework-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-only-in-dev-mode) and several other posts. They didn't help me to resolve my problem.

I've created a project using Typesafe Activator 1.2.12 and `play-scala` template. I also employed Slick 2.1.0.

I want to embed h2 database with h2gis extension into play.

When the Play project is started using `activator run`, the following `Execution exception` is displayed in the browser:

[image]

The following stack trace is on the console:

```
18013 [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] ERROR application -

! @6kmnab7c4 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/2] ->

@6kmnab7c4: Execution exception in null:null
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:296)
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:402)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$14$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:205)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$14$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:202)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
    at scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:215)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:191)
    at scala.util.Failure.recover(Try.scala:215)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:324)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:324)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:46)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248)
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:23)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:41)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/vividsolutions/jts/io/ParseException
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$1.apply(Action.scala:523)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:130)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:130)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:129)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:128)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:128)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:121)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.DoneIteratee$$anonfun$mapM$2.apply(Iteratee.scala:705)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.DoneIteratee$$anonfun$mapM$2.apply(Iteratee.scala:705)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/vividsolutions/jts/io/ParseException
    at org.h2.value.DataType.convertToValue(DataType.java:1039)
    at org.h2.engine.FunctionAlias$JavaMethod.getValue(FunctionAlias.java:500)
    at org.h2.expression.JavaFunction.getValue(JavaFunction.java:39)
    at org.h2.expression.JavaFunction.optimize(JavaFunction.java:63)
    at org.h2.expression.JavaFunction.optimize(JavaFunction.java:58)
    at org.h2.expression.Function.optimize(Function.java:2104)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Select.prepare(Select.java:831)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:248)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:442)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:384)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1188)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:73)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:665)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$SessionDef$class.prepareStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:152)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.prepareStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:389)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.results(StatementInvoker.scala:32)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.iteratorTo(StatementInvoker.scala:22)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.Invoker$class.foreach(Invoker.scala:64)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.foreach(StatementInvoker.scala:16)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.Invoker$class.firstOption(Invoker.scala:29)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.firstOption(StatementInvoker.scala:16)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.Invoker$class.first(Invoker.scala:36)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.first(StatementInvoker.scala:16)
    at controllers.Application$$anonfun$hi$1$Global$2$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(Application.scala:45)
    at controllers.Application$$anonfun$hi$1$Global$2$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(Application.scala:39)
    at scala.slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$class.withSession(DatabaseComponent.scala:34)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseFactoryDef$$anon$4.withSession(JdbcBackend.scala:61)
    at controllers.Application$$anonfun$hi$1$Global$2$.onStart(Application.scala:39)
    at controllers.Application$$anonfun$hi$1.apply(Application.scala:61)
    at controllers.Application$$anonfun$hi$1.apply(Application.scala:27)
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(Action.scala:464)
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(Action.scala:464)
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(Action.scala:433)
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(Action.scala:432)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$.invokeBlock(Action.scala:556)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$.invokeBlock(Action.scala:555)
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$1.apply(Action.scala:518)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vividsolutions.jts.io.ParseException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 55 more
```

However, if I execute `activator dist`, and run the application **it works well** (!)

The jar file for h2 is in `lib` and in sbt's reference, and without using h2gis, no error occurs.

The source code of the project is on GitHub as [weird-error](https://github.com/xchen-tian/weird-error) project. Use the project to face the error.

Update:

Here is the trace output with command `./activator run -J-XX:+TraceClassLoading`
I only paste a part of it, it seems `CoordinateArraySequence` raise the exception.

```
[Loaded scala.slick.util.ReadAheadIterator$class from file:/Users/myusername/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.slick/slick_2.11/bundles/slick_2.11-2.1.0.jar]
[Loaded scala.slick.jdbc.SQLInterpolation$ from file:/Users/myusername/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.slick/slick_2.11/bundles/slick_2.11-2.1.0.jar]
[Loaded scala.slick.jdbc.SQLInterpolationResult from file:/Users/myusername/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.slick/slick_2.11/bundles/slick_2.11-2.1.0.jar]
[Loaded scala.slick.jdbc.GetResult$GetString$ from file:/Users/myusername/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.slick/slick_2.11/bundles/slick_2.11-2.1.0.jar]
[Loaded scala.slick.jdbc.Invoker$$anonfun$firstOption$1 from file:/Users/myusername/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.slick/slick_2.11/bundles/slick_2.11-2.1.0.jar]
[Loaded com.vividsolutions.jts.io.WKTReader from file:/Users/myusername/p/scala/weird-error/lib/jts-1.13.jar]
[Loaded com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.impl.CoordinateArraySequence from file:/Users/myusername/p/scala/weird-error/lib/jts-1.13.jar]
[Loaded com.vividsolutions.jts.util.Assert from file:/Users/myusername/p/scala/weird-error/lib/jts-1.13.jar]
[Loaded com.vividsolutions.jts.util.AssertionFailedException from file:/Users/myusername/p/scala/weird-error/lib/jts-1.13.jar]
[Loaded scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1 from file:/Users/myusername/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.11.1.jar]
[Loaded play.api.Application$$anonfun$4 from file:/Users/myusername/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play_2.11/jars/play_2.11-2.3.7.jar]
[Loaded play.core.SourceMapper$$anonfun$sourceFor$1 from file:/Users/myusername/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play_2.11/jars/play_2.11-2.3.7.jar]
[Loaded scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$$anonfun$1 from file:/Users/myusername/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.11.1.jar]
[Loaded play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anon$1$$anon$2$$anonfun$sourceOf$1 from file:/Users/myusername/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.pla
y/play_2.11/jars/play_2.11-2.3.7.jar]
[Loaded scala.Option$$anonfun$orNull$1 from file:/Users/myusername/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.11.1.jar]
[Loaded play.PlayReloader$$anon$1$$anonfun$findSource$1 from file:/Users/myusername/.ivy2/cache/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/jars/sbt-plugin-2.3.7.jar]
[Loaded play.PlayReloader$$anon$1$$anonfun$findSource$1$$anonfun$apply$8 from file:/Users/myusername/.ivy2/cache/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/jars/sbt-plug
in-2.3.7.jar]
[Loaded play.PlayReloader$$anon$1$$anonfun$findSource$1$$anonfun$apply$8$$anonfun$apply$9 from file:/Users/myusername/.ivy2/cache/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plu
gin/jars/sbt-plugin-2.3.7.jar]
[Loaded play.PlayReloader$$anon$1$$anonfun$findSource$1$$anonfun$apply$8$$anonfun$apply$10 from file:/Users/myusername/.ivy2/cache/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/com.typesafe.play/sbt-pl
ugin/jars/sbt-plugin-2.3.7.jar]
[Loaded play.PlayReloader$$anon$1$$anonfun$findSource$1$$anonfun$apply$11 from file:/Users/myusername/.ivy2/cache/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/jars/sbt-plu
gin-2.3.7.jar]
[Loaded play.PlayReloader$$anon$1$$anonfun$findSource$2 from file:/Users/myusername/.ivy2/cache/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/jars/sbt-plugin-2.3.7.jar]
[Loaded play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anon$1$$anon$2$$anonfun$sourceOf$2 from file:/Users/myusername/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.pla
y/play_2.11/jars/play_2.11-2.3.7.jar]
[Loaded play.core.SourceMapper$$anonfun$sourceFor$2 from file:/Users/myusername/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play_2.11/jars/play_2.11-2.3.7.jar]
[Loaded play.api.Application$$anonfun$handleError$1 from file:/Users/myusername/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play_2.11/jars/play_2.11-2.3.7.jar]
[Loaded play.api.Application$$anonfun$handleError$2 from file:/Users/myusername/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play_2.11/jars/play_2.11-2.3.7.jar]
[Loaded scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$$anon$1 from file:/Users/myusername/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.11.1.jar]
[Loaded scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$$anonfun$stripMargin$1 from file:/Users/myusername/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.11.1.jar]
18361 [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] ERROR application -

! @6kpj6pec5 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/2] ->
```

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` usually occurs if the wrong _version_ of a class is there. For example, an old version of the jts jar file.

Comment: @ThomasMueller I recompile jts source code. It doesn't help. Still the same error.

Comment: Well maybe the version is too new. H2 uses version 1.13 I think.

Comment: Could you please rerun with the VM option `-XX:+TraceClassLoading` (given you are using a Sun/Oracle VM)?

Comment: @ThomasMueller I use the exact same version as H2gis use.

Comment: It looks like you have the following problem: During startup, some values are read from your h2 database. There seems to be a problem during parsing and Java/Scala tries to raise an Exception of type "com.vividsolutions.jts.io.ParseException". But because of some problems with the class loader, the Java VM cannot load the according class. So the root cause is the invalid data is the h2 database. The problem during error reporting follows after that error. Unfortunately the problem with the class loader is not part of the trace excerpt you posted, so I can only speculate on this.

Comment: @stefan.schwetschke Hi, the trace is pretty long. You can view it via link: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xchen-tian/weird-error/master/trace.log

Answer (score 1):

Try adding those dependencies to your build.sbt file instead of putting jars inside lib.

```
"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.1.0",
"org.orbisgis" % "h2gis" % "1.1.0",
"com.vividsolutions" % "jts" % "1.13"
```

in dev mode, play sbt would use multiple classloaders to support hot-reloading whereas after dist there will only be one classloader to handle your project. With that said, putting stuff all at the same place might solve your issue.

Comment: I tried and it didn't work. It seems "org.orbisgis" % "h2gis" % "1.1.0" has nothing inside. I use  "org.orbisgis" % "h2-dist" % "1.1.0" instead.